# How to filter documents in a collection if any of their properties has 'x' word? (MongoDB driver, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, linq, driver

Let's say I have documents in a collection called "alerts" with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f299ed8905bcf0001cd9a56"
    },
    "CreatedDate": {
        "$date": "2020-08-04T17:46:00.862Z"
    },
    "Name": "Alert name",
    "Description": "Alert description",
    "AlertTypeId": {
        "$oid": "5f299ea7905bcf0001cd9a54"
    }
    "AlertTrigger": {
        "Variation": "moreThan",
        "Amount": 5
    },
    "Emails": ["hello@hotmail.com", "test@gmail.com"]
}
```

In my .Net app I have the class representation as:

```
[BsonCollection("alerts")]
public class Alert
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string AlertTypeId { get; set; }

    public AlertTrigger AlertTrigger { get; set; }

    public ICollection<string> Emails { get; set; }
}

public class AlertTrigger
{
    public string Variation { get; set; }

    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is to filter documents that contain certain "keyword" in any of their properties.
For example, if I filter by the word "moreThan" or the word "hello", the element above would be found, because they are contained in its properties.

How can I achieve this using MongoDB Driver, LinQ, C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# Linq abstraction does not contain a way to do this. However, in MongoDB, you'll be able to create a text index on all the fields in your collection.

```js
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

Then you'll be able to do a text search on your collection in C# by writing the following.

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var db = client.GetDatabase("text");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Alert>("alerts");

var filter = Builders<Alert>.Filter.Text("moreThan");

var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I ended up trying the approach with Contains()  --> var filterDefinition = builder.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(filterKey)).
But I'll try your solution, it might be better for this.
Thanks!